# Using getElementsBy??Name in Excel VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, queryselector

I'm attempting to use VBA to scrape the link to a .gif file from this HTML fragment:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div id='imageDiv' style='width:99%'>
 <img style='width:99% !important; border:5px solid silver;' src="http://www.[rest of link].gif" alt="" />
  </div>
```

My code below :

```
parent_url = "http://www.[webpage url]" 
objIE.navigate parent_url
        While objIE.Busy Or objIE.readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend
        For Each ele In objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("imageDiv")
           If InStr(ele.Style, "width") > 0 Then
              ws1.Cells(2, 2) = ele.innerText: Exit For
           End If
        Next
objIE.Quit
```

This doesn't write anything to the spreadsheet even when I try a number of different element types. 
Any pointers about what I'm doing wrong here?
TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, as pointed out by Tim Williams, `imageDiv` is an `id` and not a tag, so it can be reached via `.getElementById()` method, which returns a unique HTML element, in contrast to `.getElementsByTagName()` which returns a collection of HTML elements.

A tag in HTML, in its simplest form looks like `<TagName>Inner Text</>`.

So in your case, the tag name you are looking for is `img` and the `id` you're looking for is `imageDiv`.

So, if you want to get the element whose `id` is `imageDiv` and then get its `img` elements, and more specifically its **first** `img` element you would have to do it like so:

```
Dim img As HTMLImg
Set img = objIE.document.getElementById("imageDiv").getElementsByTagName("img")(0)
```

Secondly, the `innerText` is not what you are looking for. What you need is the `src`.

This can be reached like so:

```
Debug.Print img.src
```

To take advantage of the `.src` property, we store the element in a `HTMLImg` variable.

The code above will print the following to your immediate window:

> http://www.[rest%20of%20link].gif/

References Used: `Microsoft HTML Object Library`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
For Each ele In objIE.document.getElementById("imageDiv").getElementsByTagName("img")
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers given it is more efficient and faster to use a css selector which returns a single node

```
Debug.Print objIE.document.querySelector("#imageDiv img").src
```